# ValueError: path 'conf/' cannot end with '/'

Tags: python, pip, graphite

I have Python 2.6.6 on Windows 7.
I'm trying to install [Graphite Tool](http://graphite.readthedocs.org/)  with pip.
But when I run the command

```
pip install carbon
```

or

```
pip install graphite-web
```

I get an error

```
ValueError: path 'conf/' cannot end with '/'
```

or

```
ValueError: path 'distro/' cannot end with '/'
```

for second command.

How can I solve this?

Update:
Full trace:

```
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'

warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>

  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_user\graphite-web\setup.py", line 64, in <module>

    **setup_kwargs

  File "C:\Python26\lib\distutils\core.py", line 152, in setup

    dist.run_commands()

  File "C:\Python26\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 975, in run_commands

    self.run_command(cmd)

  File "C:\Python26\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 995, in run_command

    cmd_obj.run()

  File "<string>", line 14, in replacement_run

  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 230, in find_sources

  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 298, in run

  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\setuptools\command\sdist.py", line 116, in __read_template_hack

  File "C:\Python26\lib\distutils\command\sdist.py", line 336, in read_template

    self.filelist.process_template_line(line)

  File "C:\Python26\lib\distutils\filelist.py", line 129, in process_template_line

    (action, patterns, dir, dir_pattern) = self._parse_template_line(line)

  File "C:\Python26\lib\distutils\filelist.py", line 104, in _parse_template_line

    dir = convert_path(words[1])

  File "C:\Python26\lib\distutils\util.py", line 201, in convert_path

    raise ValueError, "path '%s' cannot end with '/'" % pathname

ValueError: path 'distro/' cannot end with '/'
```

Comment: Where does the error happen?

Comment: please provide full traceback of the error

Comment: Seems to be a problem with linux/windows path differences. In windows path cannot end with '/' while in linux it would end with that.

Answer (score 1):

In the `setup.py` file, please remove "/" from the packages line. This issue occurs with windows.

Previous syntax:

```
package_data={'distro': ['distro/','conf/']},
```

New syntax:

```
package_data={'distro': ['distro','conf']},
```